# Global Assembly Cache registration using Installshield

Tags: installshield, gac, installshield-2012

Installshield Edition :We are using Installshield 2012 premier edition.

Issue Facing: Unable to register the DLL files to GAC (Global Assembly Cache) using Installshield 2012.

Installshield Implementaion :

**Step 1** : created one component under a feature and kept the destination as [Global assembly Cache] folder.

**Step 2** : In same component under "Advance Setting" have created a "New .Net Assembly" and provide the details along with the "Publictokenkey".

**All our assemblies are Strongly Named**.

Our aim is to place our assemblies into  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL" location for the registration of our binaries into GAC.

Kindly provide your suggestions regarding this.

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you get an error when building the msi? Or when installing the msi? Please provide more details

Comment: Hi Lars, Thanks a lot for your response, During install, I am not facing any error or failures . Even in log files also I am not getting any error code.In ISM file, I have set the value for ".net Scan at Build" as "none" and "Dependencies and properties" in that GAC component. But after installation those files are not getting copied under GAC folder as expected.

Comment: And you are aware there are two locations a dll in the GAC could be, depending on the CLR version of the dll? Have you also looked in C:\Windows\assembly? And don't forget the other folders in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly.

Comment: As we are using .Net framework 4.0 . DLL GAC registration will happen in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL"

When we tried to register this DLL through GACUTIL.exe from Visual studio SDK, The files are registered inside the above directory(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL). But when we implement the same from INSTALLSHIELD its not getting registered in both the location "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL" and "C:\Windows\assembly"

Comment: Any update plzzzz

Comment: Sounds like an installshield thing. I can't help you with that

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.